# SPFX, CSOM for SPO Development

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, spfx

I need to surface some information from SPO within SPO page. I am familiar with on-premise CSOM script webparts where I simply added JavaScript and CSOM code.

In SPO, can I still use the same approach (as I can see that new releases of CSOM are available) or will I have to learn something new like SPFX/React ?

I found a [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/spfx-part-1-sharepoint-framework-spfx-overview/) on the subject of SPFX and seems quite involved.

What is the easiest way to meet my requirements with limited learning involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online CSOM/JSOM can still be used in Classic Site and Page.
But for Modern Page/Site, it is necessary to use SPFX solution to do customization, not supported to use CSOM/JSOM in the page directly.
If you are only using classic page, use CSOM is enough.